# Filter a dict of dict

Tags: python, dictionary, filter

I'm new in Python and I am not sure it is a good idea to use dict of dict but here is my question.
I have a dictionary of dictionaries and I want to filter by the key of the inside dict:

```
a = { 'key1' : {'id1' :[0,1,2] , 'id2' :[0,1,2], 'id3' :[4,5,6]},
     'key2' : {'id3' :[0,1,2] , 'id4' :[0,1,2]},
     'key3' : {'id3' :[0,1,2] , 'id1' :[4,5,6]}
   }
```

For exemple , I want to filter by 'id1' to have :

```
result = { 'key1' : {'id1' :[0,1,2] },
           'key3' : {'id1' :[4,5,6]}
         }
```

I have tried the filter method by I get all the value:

```
r = [('key1' ,{'id1' :[0,1,2] , 'id2' :[0,1,2], 'id3' :[4,5,6]}),
     ('key3' , {'id3' :[0,1,2] , 'id1' :[4,5,6]})
   ]
```

Furthermore the filter method returns a list and I want to keep the format as a dict.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you need to use some data processing technique. Given your output specification you probably need use custom objects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
>>> { k: v['id1'] for k,v in a.items() if 'id1' in v }
{'key3': [4, 5, 6], 'key1': [0, 1, 2]}
```

For Python 2.x you might prefer to use `iteritems()` instead of `items()` and you'll still need a pretty recent python (2.7 I think) for a dictionary comprehension: for older pythons use:

```
dict((k, v['id1']) for k,v in a.iteritems() if 'id1' in v )
```

If you want to extract multiple values then I think you are best to just write the loops out in full:

```
def query(data, wanted):
    result = {}
    for k, v in data.items():
        v2 = { k2:v[k2] for k2 in wanted if k2 in v }
        if v2:
            result[k] = v2
    return result
```

giving:

```
>>> query(a, ('id1', 'id2'))
{'key3': {'id1': [4, 5, 6]}, 'key1': {'id2': [0, 1, 2], 'id1': [0, 1, 2]}}
```

Comment: this works great but actually I don't want to filter over only one value but a list value (eg. ['id1,'id2'])

Answer (score 2):

According to the precision you gave to Duncan, here is another filtering on a list using dictionary comprehension:

```
>>> my_list = ['id1', 'id2']
>>> {k1 : {k2: v2 for (k2, v2) in a[k1].iteritems() if k2 in my_list} for k1 in a}
{'key3': {'id1': [4, 5, 6]}, 'key2': {}, 'key1': {'id2': [0, 1, 2], 'id1': [0, 1, 2]}}
```

EDIT: you can also remove empty values with another dict compreehension, but that "begins" to be difficult to read... :-)

```
>>> {k3: v3 for k3, v3 in {k1 : {k2: v2 for (k2, v2) in a[k1].iteritems() if k2 in my_list} for k1 in a}.iteritems() if v3}
{'key3': {'id1': [4, 5, 6]}, 'key1': {'id2': [0, 1, 2], 'id1': [0, 1, 2]}}
```

Comment: pity about that empty dictionary lurking in the middle. I think at that point it is worth giving up on dictionary comprehensions and just write everything out in full: see my updated answer

Answer (score 1):

You can do with a dictionary comprehension:

```
def query(data, query):
    return {key : {query : data[key][query]} 
            for key in data if query in data[key]}
```

You have to look at each entry of the dictionary, which can cost a lot of time if you have many entries or do this a lot. A database with a index can speed this up.

Comment: Actually I am parsing a big csv file (30 mb) , so how could I improve the speed ?

Answer (score 1):

```
field = 'id1'
dict( (k,{field: d[field]}) for k,d in a.items() if field in d)
```

Comment: Good for Pythons < 2.7 which don't have dict comprehensions.